# How to extract the code from a Proc object?

Tags: ruby

Given a Proc object, is it possible to look at the code inside it?

For example:

```
p = Proc.new{test = 0}
```

What I need is for some way to get the string "test = 0" from a Proc object that has already been created.

Comment: For web searches, another way to say this is "inspect the code inside a Proc."

Comment: It's been a couple years since this question was asked. Anyone know if there have been any recent developments in this area?

Comment: more recent answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15024732/109175 ("use sourcify")

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [ruby2ruby](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby2ruby) library:

```
>> # tested with 1.8.7
>> require "parse_tree"
=> true
>> require "ruby2ruby"
=> true
>> require "parse_tree_extensions"
=> true
>> p = Proc.new{test = 0}
>> p.to_ruby
=> "proc { test = 0 }"
```

You can also turn this string representation of the proc back to ruby and call it:

```
>> eval(p.to_ruby).call
0
```

---

More about ruby2ruby in this video: [Hacking with ruby2ruby](http://rubyconf2008.confreaks.com/hacking-with-ruby2ruby.html).

Answer (score 13):

In case you're using Ruby 1.9, you can use [the sourcify gem](https://github.com/ngty/sourcify)

```
$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > require 'sourcify'
             => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > p = Proc.new{test = 0}
             => #<Proc:0xa4b166c@(irb):2> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > p.to_source
             => "proc { test = 0 }"
```

Comment: The sourcify gem is now unmaintained: https://github.com/ngty/sourcify/issues/34#issuecomment-75375440

Answer (score 12):

Use `proc.source_location` to get the location of the source file that defines the proc.
It also returns the line number of the definition.
You can use those values to locate the location of the proc source.

Comment: This isn't literally an answer to this question. However, it's helped me debug a problem like this where the proc wasn't coming from where I thought it was. So +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use [ParseTree](http://rubyforge.org/projects/parsetree/) for this, it also seems that support for Ruby 1.9.2 is [getting close](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-debugger/browse_thread/thread/9e8aae7aa1656add?pli=1).

Comment: ParseTree reaches EOL  with Ruby 1.8.