# Ruby comparison operations for Proc?

Tags: ruby

The comparison operator outlined [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) (shown below) on ruby 2.2.0 is really just a comparison of the Proc#call result with another object.  The documentation reads:

> proc === obj → result_of_proc
>
> Invokes the block
> with obj as the proc's parameter like #call. It is to allow a proc
> object to be a target of when clause in a case statement.

What I'm looking for is something to the effect of:

```
a = Proc.new { puts 'hi' }
b = Proc.new { puts 'hi' }

a == b
# => true
```

Can this somehow be done?

Trying to solve for a cache invalidation problem on [this](https://gist.github.com/whiteotter/d3a11b499349d826b81d) gist (code shown below). If there's already a cache file, then any change to the Kinescope block will be ignored.

```
module Kinescope
  def self.film(reel,&block)
    file_name = "kinescoped_#{reel}.ml"
    begin
      Marshal.load(File.read(file_name))
    rescue
      data = yield
      File.open(file_name,'w') do |f|
        f.write(Marshal.dump(data))
      end
      data
    end
  end
end
 
def time_consuming_calculation
  sleep 60
  true
end
 
test = Kinescope.film :big_data do
  # 'film' gigantic data here
  result = []
  File.foreach('big_file.txt') do |line|
    result << line if time_consuming_calculation
  end
  result
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called the *Function Problem* and is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem. Think about it. If this were possible, then you could solve the Halting Problem like this:

```
infinite_loop = -> { nil while true }
some_program == infinite_loop # => true
```

Ergo, it is impossible to algorithmically determine whether two programs compute the same function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [decompose procs back into Ruby source code strings using `ruby2ruby`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811501/how-to-extract-the-code-from-a-proc-object), then compare them. However, to handle some subtle differences such as variable names that do not affect behavior you may want to get a syntax tree instead and write some more sophisticared comparison.

Bear in mind that this approach is a comparison of code, not the functions' effect. It will not be able to detect two functions that do the same thing if they are written differently.